# CRUD operations for a patient database

Tags: php, object-oriented, html, mysql, crud

My code performs CRUD operations in PHP using OOP and dynamic queries. How can I completely separate HTML tables from this code?

Db.php

```
class Db {

Protected $conn;
public $table;
public $fields;
public $values;
public $sql;
public $array_keys;
public $array_values;


//put your code here
public function __construct() {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "abdullah123";

    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=Pathalogy_Lab", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function tableData($fields, $table) {

    unset($fields['Patient_data']);
    unset($fields['logout']);
    unset($fields['insert_Report']);

    $this->array_keys = array_keys($fields);
    $this->array_values = array_values($fields);

    $this->table = $table;

    $this->sqlQuery();
}

public function tableColums() {
    return "`" . implode("`, `", $this->array_keys) . "`";

}

public function tableValues() {
    return "'" . implode("', '", $this->array_values) . "'";
}

public function sqlQuery() {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$this->table}` (" . $this->tableColums() . ") VALUES (" . $this->tableValues() . ");";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if (Patient == $this->table) {
        $this->addPatient();
    } elseif (Reports == $this->table) {
        $this->addReport();
    }
}


public function addPatient() {

    header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/insert_report.php');
}

public function addReport() {

    header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/Admin_Index.php');
}

public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION["dbuser_name"], $_SESSION["dbpassword"], $_SESSION["dbid"]);
    session_unset();
    Session_destroy();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['dbuser_name']) || !isset($_SESSION['Patient_password']) || !isset($_SESSION['Patient_ID'])) {
        header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/Index.php');
        exit();
    }
}

}
```

Admin.php

```
class Admin extends Db {

public $data_id;

public function listRecord() {

    if (isset($_SESSION['dbuser_name']) && isset($_SESSION['dbpassword'])) {


        $query = "select Patient_ID, Patient_name, Patient_Address, Patient_Phone from Patient where Role= 'u'";
        $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $result->execute(); 

        if ($row_count > 0) {
            // output data of each row

            $this->detailsHeredocs();
            $nust = $result->fetchall();

            foreach ($nust as $row1) {

                echo"       
<tr> 
<td>  $row1[Patient_name]    </td>
<td>  $row1[Patient_Address] </td>

<td><a href='../Admin/AdminData.php?report_id=$row1[Patient_ID]'>Details</a></td>

</tr>";
            }
            echo <<<HTML
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myTable').DataTable();
  }); 
  </script>
            </body>
            </html>
 HTML;
        }
    }
}

public function Details($id) {

    $this->data_id = $id;

    if (isset($_SESSION['dbuser_name']) && isset($_SESSION['dbpassword'])) {

        $query = "select Report_type, Report_Id, Report_Reults,Patient_name, Patient_Address, "
                . "Patient_Phone from Patient join Reports WHERE "
                . "Reports.Patient_ID=$this->data_id and Patient.Patient_ID=$this->data_id";

        $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $row = $result->execute();
        $row_count = $result->rowCount();

        if ($row_count > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            $this->patientListHeredocs();
            $nust = $result->fetchAll();
            foreach ($nust as $row1) {

                echo"       
                <tr>
                    <td>  $row1[Patient_name]    </td>
                    <td>  $row1[Patient_Address] </td>
                    <td>  $row1[Patient_Phone]   </td>
                    <td>  $row1[Report_type]     </td>
                    <td>  $row1[Report_Reults]   </td>
                          <td><a href='../Admin /AdminData.php?del_id=$row1[Report_Id]'>Delete</a></td>
                </tr>";
            }
            echo <<<HTML
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myTable').DataTable();
 }); 
 </script>
            </body>
            </html>
HTML;
        }
    }
 }

 public function Delete($del) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['dbuser_name']) && isset($_SESSION['dbpassword'])) {

        $this->data_id = $del;

        $query = "DELETE FROM Reports Where Report_Id=$this->data_id";

        $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
        $affected_rows = $result->rowCount();
        if ($affected_rows == 1) {

            header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/Admin_Index.php');
        } else {

            echo 'No data DELEted';
        }
    }
 } 

 public function DeletePatient($param) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['dbuser_name']) &&   isset($_SESSION['dbpassword'])) {

        $this->data_id = $param;
        $query = "Delete from Patient WHERE Patient_ID=$this->data_id";
        $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();

        header('Location: ../Admin/Admin_Index.php');
    }
}

public function PatientList() {

    if (isset($_SESSION['dbuser_name']) &&       isset($_SESSION['dbpassword'])) {

        $query = "select Patient_ID, Patient_name, Patient_Address, Patient_Phone from Patient where Role= 'u'";

        $result = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
        $row_count = $result->rowCount();

        if ($row_count > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            ob_start();
            include("../FrontEndFiles/navBar.html");
            include("../FrontEndFiles/sideBar.html");
            $include = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            echo <<<HTML
    {$include}


       <div class="col-md-8"> 
            <h2> Data</h2>
                <table id="myTable" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Patient Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                        <tbody> 
 HTML;
            $nust = $result->fetchAll();
            foreach ($nust as $row1) {
                    echo"       
                            <tr>
                                <td>  $row1[Patient_name]    </td>     
                                <td><a href='../Admin/AdminData.php?deleteData=$row1[Patient_ID]'>Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>";
                    }
echo <<<HTML
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myTable').DataTable();
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
        }
    }
    }

    public function loginAdmin($login_admin) {

    if (!empty($login_admin[0]) || !empty($login_admin[1])) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE Patient_name  =             '$login_admin[0]' and Patient_password = $login_admin[1] and Role = 'a'";
        $stmt = $this->conn->query($query);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $row['Patient_name'];
        echo $row['Patient_password'];
        echo $row['Patient_ID'];

        if ($row) {

            $_SESSION["dbuser_name"] = $row['Patient_name'];
            $_SESSION["dbpassword"] = $row['Patient_password'];
            $_SESSION["dbid"] = $row['Patient_ID'];

            header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/Admin_Index.php');
        } else {

            header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/AdminLogin.php');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/AdminLogin.php');
    }
    }

    public function detailsHeredocs() {

    ob_start();
    include("../FrontEndFiles/navBar.html");
    include("../FrontEndFiles/sideBar.html");
    $include = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo <<<HTML
  {$include} 

       <div class="col-md-8">  
        <h2>Report's Data</h2>
    <table id="myTable" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Patient Address</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

HTML;
}

public function patientListHeredocs() {
    ob_start();
    include("../FrontEndFiles/navBar.html");
    include("../FrontEndFiles/sideBar.html");
    $include = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo <<<HTML
    {$include}

       <div class="col-md-8"> 

        <h2>Data</h2>
    <table id="myTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Patient Name</th>
                <th>Patient Address</th>
                <th>Patient Phone</th>
                <th>Report Type</th>
                <th>Report Results</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>


HTML;
 }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `completely separate HTML tables from this code`?  do you not want Tables rendered on your page?

Comment: @Malachi The question is about how to organize the code to separate the presentation from the business logic.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote about 'poor-mans MVC' [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153047/registering-users-bank-account-and-logging-in-securely/153049#153049), but I'll write about it again for you.

Basically, you want to separate your code into 'Models', 'Views' and 'Controllers'. The 'Controller' does the brunt of the PHP work, and it fills a 'Model' with some data. Then the 'Controller' passes the aforementioned 'Model' off to the 'View', which simply displays what is in the 'Model'.

I'll work up some examples later today and tonight if I get time, but your 'View' should have as minimal PHP code as possible. Basically it should just display everything from your 'Model'.

I've gotten an example together [in another question on this site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154778/building-a-model-view-controller-application-in-php). Basically, you should be able to take that code, build the proper structure, and then build your `Controller`, `Model` and `View` objects as necessary.

---

I wouldn't inherit `Db` as a class, I would implement it and let it expose a clean API. Inheriting it implies that the `Admin` class *should* be used in places where `Db` would belong, but creating and instance of it is the right way to do it. Then you can build a clean API like: `$db->GetData('tableName', 'columnList')` which would query `tableName` for `columnList` (i.e. `*`) then return the resultant arrays.

Your current `Db`/`Admin` class violate SRP (single-responsibility principle): the idea that any code should have one purpose and one purpose only. The `Db` class should be responsible for querying and returning data from the DB, not for transforming that data to HTML and such, sending headers, etc. `Admin` should not inherit `Db`, because *the `Admin` class is not an extension of `Db`*. It doesn't add or change functionality regarding `Db` itself, it wraps it with a UI.

---

Other than that your naming is inconsistent. You have `listRecord` and `Details` which are both `public` functions, I don't know what the PHP standard is but pick a casing scheme and stick with it in that context, it's usually easier to identify/find information in it later.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not do what you said it does (*My code performs CRUD operations in PHP using OOP and dynamic queries*). At least not in the way I would expect it. It does much more. And your way of using OOP just uses the possibility to extend a class. But even your base class *DB* already does completely not db related stuff (issuing location headers is no db-task, isn't it). And your *Admin* class does things like getting patient details - what has this to do with *admin*? Or doing the acutal login for the admin and then redirect - that's not db related again.

I was quite surprised to see a method sqlQuery() do an insert without any params.

Please use a class for a single thing. If you want to do redirects in a class, then create an extra class that is only used for the redirects.

What your question sounds like is more like using a MVC-scheme. Model (= database), view (= html code) and controller (= logic to connect model and view). There are good frameworks out there, that would definitly help you to do it. Or you can do it yourself.

Some basic structure you might use - if you do not want a MVC framework:

Database-Classes:

**IMPORTANT: no html code and no redirects in these classes. ONLY db related stuff!**

- abstract class DB   - common database things like connection pooling, getting the database connection, basic query functionality - but in no way for a specific table
- class Admin extends DB  - get admin credentials
- class Patient extends DB - all patient related stuff
- class PatientRecords extends DB - the PatientRecords

*Might have missed a few other tables.*

And then you have php files for each request (or a single index.php that handles all requests). In this file(s) you need to load the appropriate database table model and do the request. The output is then in these php files or in even other files you might include. You might want some helper classes, like checking if the user is logged in.

But in any way you project sounds like you should use a MVC framework.